# Tumblr | Creating custom thumbnails for iframe videos

Tags: css, thumbnails, tumblr

I'm working on a custom Tumblr where I will be uploading my own videos (not linking through Youtube or Vimeo).

I'd like to control the dimensions and size of the thumbnails. After digging through the documentation I can't find anything concerning how Tumblr generates the thumbnail images (poster).

While there's a {VideoThumbnailURL} block for videos uploaded via Youtube, etc,
{block:VideoThumbnail}{VideoThumbnailURL}{/block:VideoThumbnail}, there doesn't seem to be one for videos uploaded to Tumblr by the user.

I am rendering the actual iFrame video player in the grid itself.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add their size directly on the HTML, you can wrap the thumbnails in a `div` and set their dimensions in your CSS.

Like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    {block:VideoThumbnail}{VideoThumbnailURL}{/block:VideoThumbnail}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbnails img{
    width: 150px;}
```

You don't need to set the `height` attribute, because once you set a fixed `width`, the browser will resize the image in proportion.